# Recreate xtgls Regression from Stata in R with panelAR

Tags: r, stata, panel-data

My goal is to reproduce regression results from Stata made with the *xtgls* command in R. I have panel-data with an ID and a time variable. The regression I am trying to reproduce is from this paper: [on researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Magali-Delmas/publication/321632016_Dataset_on_Information_Strategies_for_Energy_Conservation_A_Field_Experiment_in_India/links/5a42a3760f7e9ba868a47fb7/Dataset-on-Information-Strategies-for-Energy-Conservation-A-Field-Experiment-in-India.pdf)
(I am trying to recreate Column 4 in Table 6)

The full dataset including the Do-Files is available here: [Harvard Dataverse](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/file.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/7MEXN4/6FWBNN&version=1.0)
(Again, I want to reproduce Table 6)

The original regression looks like this:

```
xtset ID TIME

and then

xtgls y a b c d f f^2 f^3 i.e i.ID, panels(heteroskedastic), corr(psar1), force
```

**This yields the exact results i want in Stata.**

My approach in R is the following:

```
library(panelAR)
panelAR(y ~ a + b + c + d + f + f^2 + f^3 + factor(e) + factor(ID), data=df, panelVar="ID", timeVar="TIME", autoCorr="psar1", panelCorrMethod="pwls")
```

**This does give me a result, but it is quite different from the Stata result.**

Given the explanations for xtgls: https://www.stata.com/manuals/xtxtgls.pdf and panelAR: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/panelAR/panelAR.pdf, I think I have pretty much recreated the same options as in the original Stata command. But it seems I am missing something.

Thanks in advance for any help/ideas on this.

Edit 1: Changed typo in xtgls + Included Stata 17 Link

Comment: The current manual entry for `xtgls` is always at https://www.stata.com/manuals/xtxtgls.pdf and is for version 17 as I write. Which version you used and whether that makes a difference I can't tell, for different reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the typo. I am using Stata 16.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify `panelCorrMethod="parks"` in the R code?

```
library(panelAR)
panelAR(y ~ a + b + c + d + f + f^2 + f^3 + factor(e) + factor(ID), data=df, panelVar="ID", timeVar="TIME", autoCorr="psar1", panelCorrMethod="parks")
```

---

Side Comment:
From a statistical/Stata coding point of view, you might also find the Stata Journal paper by Hoechle interesting (https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1536867X0700700301)